# How does one characterize or classify the patriotic music in American films & TV?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I am not a musician, theorist, or composer, so I don't have a lot of musical vocabulary at my disposal. But there's a certain kind of music in films about American bravery and freedom: I can recognize it instantly, but I can't articulate what it is or how it works. Examples include:

- The [theme music](https://youtu.be/gHj7MZSA8rA) from "The West Wing"
- The [opening music](https://youtu.be/0HUf68gFGEE) from *Saving Private Ryan*
- [This promotion](https://youtu.be/ecQNbs-fZ98) for a short film about World War II, produced by the WWII Museum in New Orleans

What is this musical style, and why is it associated with American patriotism?

Answer (score 3):

If you listen closely, behind the heroic-sounding brass instruments there are sneaky snare drums. These are all [military marches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trZlvpLihHk), just played much slower and super poignant-like.

> A march, as a musical genre, is a piece of music with a strong regular rhythm which in origin was expressly written for marching to and most frequently performed by a military band
>   ...
>   The most important instruments are various drums (especially snare drum), horns, fife or woodwind instruments and brass instruments
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_(music)

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-IoH9VCVXg) is one that is not so slow, and thus more recognizable as a march.

I can think of two reasons why these marches might feel patriotic to you. First, a lot of national anthems are marches, including the Star-Spangled Banner. Second, if you are US American, you probably associate marches with the revolutionary war, a period that is at the foundation of your patriotism.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Alvaro, and thanks for a great answer.  I added some details on the genre to flesh it out just a little more.  You might also add a note on what makes this specifically "American" as specified in the original question.